# Why is certain motor oil noisy?

Tags: engine, oil-change

I recently used a product with 100% PAO base.
However, there is an unprecedented noise.

I wonder if it's my car's problem or if certain oils can be noisy.

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with asking a question that you know the answer to, there's no reason to create a sock-puppet account to pretend to be another user.